# SQLAlchemy substring filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have stored types of Bags in my PostgreSQL database:["Clutch Bags", "Shoulder Bags", "Tote Bags"]. I am writing a python flask based API endpoint using which a user can provide a search term like "Red Shoulder Bag" or "Grey Clutch Bag". Now I want to write a query using SQLAlchemy so that for these given search terms I am able to look for that value in my Bags table. I wrote this, but it only works if user entered search string is plural, this doesnt work if user enters 'Grey Clutch Bag'

```
    categories = db.session.query(Bags.id) \
    .filter(literal(search_string).ilike(func.concat('%', Bags.type, '%')))\
    .all()
```

how can I strip the trailing 's' from bag types in database at the time of filtering? I want to be able to query such that:

```
type_in_db = "Clutch Bags" 
search_string = "Grey Clutch Bag"

if type_in_db.rstrip('s') in search_string:
    return type_in_db
```

Comment: As to the error, `func.lower(Bags.type) in search_string`  is equal to `search_string.__contains__(func.lower(Bags.type))` and so you get the error, since [`str.__contains__` expects another string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in).

Comment: It looks like you've got too many closing paren as well.

Comment: you says I have stored types of Bags in my PostgreSQL database: but tag say mysql?

Comment: If your query contains a word that the database doesn't contain, you will not get a match. This may seem obvious, but your question seems to suggest that you expect that searching for "Grey Clutch Bag" will yield "Clutch Bags" from the database. I recommend editing your question to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very expirienced python developer but why not simply:

```
 categories = db.session.query(Bags.id) \
.filter(Bags.type.like('%'+search_string+'%'))\
.all()
```

Comment: This is the answer. To make it more concrete, `.filter(Bags.type.like('%Clutch Bag%'))` will match "Grey Clutch Bags".

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for "Clutch Bags" and "Grey Clutch Bag" to match with a simple `LIKE` or "contains".  You *must* rethink your design.

Here are some thoughts in that direction.

In MySQL there is a `FULLTEXT` type of index that works with "words".  It understands English singular/plural so that "Bags" and "Bag" will match each other.  However, there are several limitations of `FULLTEXT`.  Your one example might not hit any of them, but other situations might.

You could "cleanse" the input -- both in building the table and building the search string.  This includes removing punctuation, pluralization, capitalization, synonyms, etc.

In the long run, you may need to avoid third-party software (such as SQLAlchemy); they tend to force you to learn both the database and their reformulation of it, plus they may prevent getting at some details that you will need.